# How to display the complete data from the grid view when the paging is enabled?

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem while displaying the data from the grid to the excel.I have implemented paging and the problem is the page that is displayed is only exported to the excel not all the pages.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating a second page that displays the data in the grid but with paging turned off. That way all the data will be exported to Excel

Answer (score 0):

If you fetch all the records from the database and store it locally then you might consider to export data from that Source. not from the datagrid as Paging is implemented it contains on the records of page size.

Answer (score 0):

//Export the actual dataset

```
            if (rds != null && rds.Tables.Count != 0)
            {

                #region WriteToTheStringBuilder
                DataTable dt = rds.Tables[0];
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder ();
                //first add the column names 
                for (int j = 0; j <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    //comm -- remove only one tab if exists from each cell
                    str.Append ( dt.Columns[j].ToString () + "\t" );
                }
                str.AppendLine();
                //comm -- than add by row the whole table

                for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                    {
                        //comm -- remove only one tab if exists from each cell
                        str.Append ( Utils.Str.Str.FindAndReplace (
                                                                                        dt.Rows[i][j].ToString (), "(.*)(\t)(.*)", "$1$3" ) + "\t" );
                    }

                    str.AppendLine();
                }
                #endregion WriteToTheStringBuilder


                #region WriteToResponse
                //<source>http://geekswithblogs.net/brcraju/archive/2005/07/27/48372.aspx</source>
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd." + fileExtension; 
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">");

                #region IftheExportingServerIsBehindFirewall
                bool flagUseDnsRemapping = false;
                flagUseDnsRemapping = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt16(Resources.GV.UseSecureConnection));

                if (flagUseDnsRemapping == true)
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Host", Resources.GV.ServerDNSName);

                #endregion IftheExportingServerIsBehindFirewall
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
                "attachment;filename=" + pageName + "." + fileExtension);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = " "; //utf will brake thinks ...
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250"); //windows-1250
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability ( HttpCacheability.NoCache );
```

//          System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter ();
//          System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite =
//new HtmlTextWriter ( stringWrite );
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write ( str.ToString () );
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.End ();
                    #endregion WriteToResponse

```
                userObj.Mc.Msg  = "Export to Excel performed successfully ";
                return true;
            } //eof if
```